# Exported JAR is not creating files it should

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar, ms-word

I created a Java app in Netbeans using swing, it does a lot of things perfectly, it also creates a folder and inside that folder it creates one ms word file and 2 images jpeg.

If I run the application in Netbeans it works as expeted, creates the folder and the files, no issues with it.

But when I export it as a jar, the jar runs fine, and also creates the folder but it won't create the word document nor the image files.

I also tried to change the path for the files but it won't create them.

I have checked the permissions in windows properties for my exported jar and it has all of them.

I'm using apache poi to create the word document and jfree chart to create the images, I'm exporting it with the menu "clean and build" in netbeans.

I can supply more info if needed, thanks for reading.

Comment: There are many different reasons programs can behave differently. It may be running under a different JVM. A different starting current directory often makes a difference. Run in a terminal so you will be sure to see any exceptions that get thrown. Add additional logging if necessary to verify the functions to generate the files are still called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ran the jar with the command window and it results that the problem is, the application does not find the resources, they are there I decompress the jar to check it. I get a file not found exception, I tried to change the path in my project but it's still the same :( I'm looking more info, but if you can please help me.

Comment: Found my issue, I changed the way it looks for the resources, it is now explained in the answer section. It now works as expected, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to WillShackleford

Well I opened a command prompt and run the jar with the "java -jar MyJar.jar" command, I got the exception that was thrown and I could see the issues, it was not finding the image.

The problem was how I coded to get the resources, it was this way:

`InputStream img = new FileInputStream("src/images/image.jpg");`

But the correct way to call a resource is:

`InputStream img = InputStream.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/image.jpg");`

I removed the 'src' since that folder does not exist in the Jar file and the '/' is used to refer to the root of the jar.